# Sending signed XML via Jax-WS and XOP/MTOM

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-signature

I' have an enveloped signed XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SolicitudRegistro xmlns...
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod...
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath>ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()='SolicitudRegistro']</XPath>
                </Transform>
            </Transforms>
      </SignedInfo>
    </Signature>
</SolicitudRegistro>
```

When I try to send it via Web Service, Jax-WS changes the request content to:

```
<SolicitudRegistro xmlns...
    <!-- Here -->
    <Signature:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:Signature="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod...
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath>ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()='SolicitudRegistro']</XPath>
                </Transform>
            </Transforms>
      </SignedInfo>
      <!-- Here -->
    </Signature:Signature>
</SolicitudRegistro>
```

The XPath transform includes some signature elements and the document is invalid. I tried to make a HttpRequest with the Soap definition on a test environment and response is expected. But, in production, the web service have MTOM optimization. What solution would you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: What is the canonicalization method you are using?